# SonarLint: Remove the unneccessary boolean literal

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarlint

I'm using the following code to select a record from an array where it's the oldest of the non deleted records.

```
const firstRec = records.filter(rec => rec.isDeleted != false)
  .reduce((a, b) => new Date(a.Created) < new Date(b.Created) ? a : b);
```

SonarLint is giving me a 'Remove the unneccessary boolean literal' error on the line:

```
 rec.isDeleted != false
```

And I can't figure out how to get rid of the error.  New to SonarLint, this seems legit.

Comment: try `records.filter(rec => !rec.isDeleted)`. Maybe it's just saying that `writing a !== false` it's the same as `!a`

Comment: Yup, just completely spaced on that one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If `rec.isDeleted` is of type `boolean`, you don't have to equate it to `true` or `false` (Its implied):

```
if(rec.isDeleted != false){}
```

Instead, do this:

```
if(rec.isDelete){}
```